# Jquery - wait until one movement is complete until the next fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope your all good... Another question :/

Heres the page im working on:

http://beelinetest.site50.net/uw_virtual_tour.html#

Its not a huge problem, but if you press the tabs quickly- two will shoot up- what can i do about this? So it waits for the first tab to complete its movement?

Also, another thing while im here, notice the slight hover over movement ive added to the tabs? When hovered over they move 7px up, then back down when un-hovered. But when clicked the tab moves up and it still thinks my mouse is on hover... Its not until i move the mouse until it moves back down 7px...

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: Try using `stop()` http://api.jquery.com/stop/ in your animation queue

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler for each tab should disable the clicks on the other tabs until the "slide in" function is complete. Looking at your code, it might be easier to accomplish if you had a common selector rather than selecting each individual one by id. Perhaps you could add a class to each div you want to use as a tab, then you could operate on them as a group.